# Flux through cylinder (vector field)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-fields, multiple-integral

How do I calculate vector fields $\mathbf F(x,y,z)=x\mathbf i+y\mathbf j+ z\mathbf k$ flux through the cylinder $S =${$ (x,y,z)\vert x^2+y^2\le 9, 0\le z \le 2$}.

I know that:

$$dr=(-3\sin\theta,3\cos\theta,0)$$

$\Phi=\int \mathbf F \cdot d^2A=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^2(3\cos\theta,3\sin\theta,z)\cdot(3\cos\theta,3\sin\theta,0)\,dzd\theta=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^29\,dzd\theta=36\pi$

Right answer is $54\pi$. I don't know where I have done mistake but it's so close that tehre are some dump mistakes.

Comment: You calculated only the flux throught the lateral surface. It has to be added the flux for the top and the bottom. It's zero for the latter (as the field is zero for the z component) and amounts $\pi 3^2·2=18\pi$ for the former (as the field has the z component constant and of value 2).

Answer (score 1):

I'd use Gauss' (Divergence) Theorem here.  The divergence of the vector field is $3$, which you integrate over the volume of the cylinder $18\pi.$ 
So you get $3(18\pi.)$  Much less painful.